# CUDA and C++ for host and device code

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I started to integrate CUDA into my C++ applications weeks ago. I've been doing my own research about integrating CUDA and C++. However, I still feel uncomfortable about this topic.

Can somebody help me to clarify some questions based on the latest Toolkit 3.2 or 4.0 RC?

1. It says Fermi fully support C++ in Fermi's white paper. Does that mean it support C++ in both host and device code or just host code?
2. What kind of C++ features I can use in kernel code? I know templates are supported. What about classes or structs?
3. Can I pass a user-defined class instance (which holds some pointers to device memory) into a kernel, and call its member function in the kernel code? Do classes and structs make any differences?

Any helps are appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your host already supports C++, doesn't it? But now the GeForce 400 Series (codename Fermi) supports C++ code on the device.
2. Classes too, with some restrictions. See **appendix D** of the [programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) for details.
3. You can pass a reference of the class. Check section **D.6.2** of the programming guide.

In general, appendix D shows the supported C++ constructs and pieces of code. It's worth reading it.